# App Icon not coming in google search autocomplete

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-app-indexing

I have implemented the AppIndexing API. I am getting the search auto completion and it is working as expected. But the app icon is not available. Today I updated the google search app on my phone and since then the app icon is not coming .
Checkout the screenshot at https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckpGj.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have defined your icon app in the manifest.xml inside your application tag:

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

I was having the same issue in an early version of my app and was fixed as soon as I added my launcher icon (the app uses an Android bot icon by default as launcher icon if nothing is provided within the application tag, but not for the AppIndexing Api).